# Wich Programming language do I need for this Programm?

Tags: windows, software-development

I just thought, wich key from my keyboard did I pressed the mosted while coding. Thats when I came up with the idea for a programm, that saves all the keyboard inputs in a file.

But I dont know wich programing language to choose for this. Mainly because I want the programm, to start save the data the moment I start my computer.

Does anyone has a idea how I can start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [What Every Developer Should Learn Early On](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/07/what-every-developer-should-learn-early-on/?cb=1) on the Stack Overflow blog:

> **There are very few cases where the language choice actually matters**. There are things you can obviously not do in some languages. If you write frontend code, you don’t get a language choice. There are also specific contexts where performance is important and X language just won’t do, those situations are quite rare. In general, language choice is usually one of the least important issues for a project.

Tl;dr it dosen't matter, just pick one that you are comfortable with.

Read about "hooking" keyboard emssages:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa
- https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

etc, etc, etc